# -skipErrors in Transactional Replication not happening

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

I have set up a transactional replication initialized using backup for a big database(1.6TB).Due to some error(space issue in the subscriber) the replication was not happening and there were replication error for the past 5 days.
So i added space and now i am getting the 20598 and 547 error in Distribution to Subscriber.

I changed the Agent profile and created a custom profile with the -skipError values as 20598:547.
I restarted the Distribution agent by stopping and starting the distribution job in the subscriber(PULL subscriber).
After restarting i see that, Distributor to Subscriber is initialized in replication monitor,but i don't see that the skipping is happening.

How can i solve this issue.?

I prefer not to drop Publisher/Subscriber as i am initializing using backup and it is a big database.

Comment: I have similar problem. -SkipError doesn't have any impact. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the "skipped # rows" in the message window?
Can you maybe post the window screenshot?

Like this blog here (it did what you did, skipped 20598:547), restarted agent
https://www.percyreyes.com/2016/07/the-skiperrors-parameter-for.html